# Seeding Phoenix Repo from json response

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to seed the database for my [Phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/up-and-running) application using the response from another api. I don't understand how to parse the response to create new object from it. I'm using [HTTPoisin](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison) and [Poison](http://hexdocs.pm/poison/) as of right now

#### seed.ex

```
alias NewsApplication.Article
HTTPoison.start

url = "rails_application.com/articles/index"

case HTTPoison.get(url) do
  {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
    articles = Poison.decode!(body["articles"])
    Enum.fetch(articles, 1, fn(a) -> IO.puts a end)
  {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 404}} ->
    IO.puts "Not found :("

  {:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason}} ->
    IO.inspect reason
end
```

#### web/model/article.ex

#### updated

```
defmodule NewsApplication.Article do
  use Ecto.Model

  schema "articles" do
    field  :label, :string
    field  :slug, :string
    field  :full_path, :string
    field  :content_cache, :string
    field  :position, :integer, default: 0
    field  :children_count, :integer, default: 0
    field  :is_published, :boolean, default: false
    field  :is_shared, :boolean, default: false
    field  :featured, :boolean, default: false
    field  :score, :integer

    timestamps
  end
end
```

#### sample response

```
{"articles":
  [{
    "article":{
      "id":436,
      "updated":"2015-08-14T11:51:21.931Z",
      "title":"Celebrating It's 50th Issue",
      "numberOfViews":0,
      "numberOfFavorites":2,
      "imageURLs":["http://.../images/1549/original/axye.png"],
      "tags":["Company News"],
      "isFeatured":false,
      "isPublished":true,
      "published":"2015-07-28T17:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: What version of Phoenix are you using? There's a new convention for Ecto models: http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-models#section-the-model

Comment: @MatthewLehner 0.16.1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're almost there, but are missing a couple of things.

You'll want to iterate through each of the article responses using `Enum.each` and save these to the database like this:

```
Article.changeset(%Article{}, json)
|> Repo.insert
```

putting it all together, it'd be something like this:

```
Enum.each articles_json, fn(article) ->
  Article.changeset(%Article{}, json)
  |> Repo.insert
end
```

This won't handle any errors on `Repo.insert` if the `changeset` is invalid, but it'll work otherwise.

I'd recommend having a read through the [Phoenix docs for models](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-models) for further reference – specifically have a look at how they're structuring create actions.

Comment: Is there a way I can view the changeset?

Comment: I get an error `(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Access not implemented for ` when trying to assign the the value `articles`

Comment: I think your model should have `use NewsApplication.Web, :model` instead of `use Ecto.Model`

Comment: If you want to try these in the console `iex -S mix phoenix.server` and you'll have access to all the Phoenix dependencies and modules.

Comment: When i try to decode the response it complaints. `json = Poison.decode!(response, as: %{'articles' => [Article]})`. `iex(7)> json = Poison.decode!(response, as: %{'articles' => [Article]})
** (ArgumentError) argument error
             :erlang.iolist_to_binary({:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body`

Comment: Using `Poison.decode!` expects that the structure of the JSON matches the structure of the the article struct. You probable want to use `Poison.parse` which will give you a map of the JSON that you can troubleshoot on.